# In an ALU, is every function calculated simultaneously?

Tags: digital-logic, cpu, alu

I'm designing a 4 bit ALU as a project. I have circuits that can calculate addition, subtraction and bitwise logic operations - my question is, do I tie A & B (4 bit inputs) to every circuit that performs an operation/function, meaning every function is carried out at once, and use a multiplexer to select which output I want? Or is there a more efficient/elegant way of performing just the operation I want on A & B? I'm not sure (traditionally) how this is done.

Comment: Usually you generate a K-map or truth table and derive the equation from there.

Comment: I understand that, I have the functions working, but do I use the multiplexer to select the result? Or to select a singular function (not allowing other functions to calculate)?

Comment: Traditionally in a simple design you let all of them run at once and choose only the result of interest.  Only letting one run could perhaps be interesting from a power consumption perspective, but would add some challenges to implement.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Perfect, just the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Traditionally it is called "microprocessor architecture", where several different and elegant ways were invented over several decades in computer science on how to manage the dataflow, like "pipelining", "reservation stations", etc., to fetch, execute, and "retire" operations. Try the Hennessy and Patterson classics to start, https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Architecture-Fifth-Quantitative-Approach/dp/012383872X

Comment: In a single-cycle ALU, yes - exactly what you described. Every function operates in parallel using combinatorial logic and a mux selects on of those function results for storage (or in the past, optionally for testing).

Comment: @eddiewastaken It's not precisely an either-or situation. Many things are calculated in parallel and selected for. But others cause a change at the beginning and there's no mux at the end to select between outputs. For example, subtraction and addition are usually NOT done in parallel, using a separate adder and separate subtractor, with a mux at the end to pick. Rather, it's usually just an adder (no subtractor) but with one of the inputs inverted and the carry-in set to 1. If you are looking for a perfect bright line answer, there isn't one.

Answer (score 4):

Look up the detailed design of SN74181 from Texas Instruments. Every logic gate will be shown. Here is a portion, from http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54s181.pdf

[image]

Comment: So is every function simultaneously calculated, and the control bits purely just select the result you want?

Comment: Examine the top right cluster of gates, used to generate Carryout. Examine the top left gates, where the 4 S0...S3 bits enter, to select the function. Examine the Carryout pin, and look for any way to inhibit it with various combinations of S0...S3. For fun, examine the AMD2901 4-bit bit-slice.

Answer (score 1):

Waste of MUX to combine separate logic gates. MUX is the ultimate any gate. 4way pass-through such as 74CBT3253 make chain comparisons without ripple. From magnitude test we can instantly solve all slices of A-B's borrow, B-A's borrow, or A+B's carry.

[image: Series Prefixed Subtractor]

With CMOS, no free XOR across coils, so 74LVC2G86 (the smaller chip) handles that. Also dropped Zero as redundant to magnitude.
[image: 8 slices of 6nS MUX with XOR]